how to write a Mongo Aggregation query using AggregateFluent in C#
I want to write a C# code for the below mongo aggregation query
[
  {
    $match: {
       uid: "8c08e94d-57f0-4b63-a232-58399070db66"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      custId: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$aas",
          as: "itemM",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$itemM.aty",
              "ABC"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      loginId: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$aas",
          as: "itemW",
          cond: {
            $eq: ["$$itemW.aty", "XYZ"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$custId"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$loginId"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      oid: "$custId.aid",
      lid: "$loginId.aid"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "device",
      let: {
        oid: "$oid",
        lid: "$lid"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: ["$id", "$$oid"]
                },
                {
                  $eq: ["$loginId", "$$lid"]
                },
                {
                  $eq: ["$trusted", true]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "devices"
    }
  }
]

I am trying to join User collection with Device collection and wan to use the AggregateFluent strongly typed approach to accomplish this and not the BsonDocument approach.
I have the EntityMapping c# classes as UserDocument and DeviceDocument in my project and want to generate an output from this query which will be of type UserDeviceDocument as below:
public class UserDeviceDocument : UserDocument 
{ 
    public List<DeviceDocument> Devices { get; set; } 
}

Can some one suggest how to write this using C# mongo driver
I tried doing it as follows:
var pipeline = new EmptyPipelineDefinition<UserDocument>();
var findResult = await userCollection.AggregateAsync(pipeline.Match(u => u.UniversalId == uId)
    .Project(user => new
    {
        loginId = user.aas.Where(a => a.aty== "XYZ").Select(a => a.aid),
        opaId = user.aas.Where(a => a.aty== "XYZ").Select(a => a.aid),
    })
    .Unwind("$loginId")
    .Unwind("$opaId")
    .Project(p => new
    {
        lid = "$loginId",
        oid = "$oapId"
    })
    .Lookup(
        deviceCollection,
        let: new BsonDocument
        {
            { "opaId1", "$oid" },
            { "loginId1", "$lid" }
        },
        lookupPipeline: new EmptyPipelineDefinition<DeviceDocument>()
        .Match(dp => dp.OpaqueId == "$opaId1" &&
        dp.LoginId == "$loginId1" && dp.Trusted == true),
        @as: (UserDeviceDocument ud) => ud.Devices
        )
    )
    .ContinueWith(predicate=>predicate.Result.ToListAsync())
    .Unwrap()
    .ConfigureAwait(false);

this gives me the below error :
System.AggregateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=One or more errors occurred. (Command aggregate failed: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'. Consider using $getField or $setField..)
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at MongoDB.MongoDbOutboundFunction.<>c.<ExecuteAggregateUserDeviceTagOperationAsync>b__53_5(Task`1 predicate) in C:\RepositoriesMongoDB\MongoDbOutboundFunction.cs:line 1982
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__272_0(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)


simplify your query to the step that actually trigger the error

not sure which part in the query is throwing this error, but even if you can give me the code using c# mongo driver

disable parts of the code one by one and see whether you still see this error or no
